# How to write a constraint in CPLEX Python

Tags: python, cplex

How can i write this constraint with python in cplex?

```
t * sum(m in M) X(j,t,m) - u * sum(m in M) X(i,u,m) >=0 for all (i,j) in J 
such that a(i,j) = 1 and i!=j, (t,u) in T such u!=t
```